# One error message for any invalid field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my login form I want to display one *simple error message* like `"Sorry, email or password is invalid"` whenever user enters invalid email and / or password; instead of standard fancy message with heading and unordered list.

Comment: The question is: how do I achieve this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for you

```
<% if user_session.errors %>
   <p>Sorry, email or password is invalid</p>
<% end %>
```

Remove the: `<%= f.error_messages %>`

If your user_session object does more specific validation you can make the `if` statement more specific.